# How to make two JSON combine?

Tags: json, angular

```
"workItemData": "{\"pendingAppointment\":{\"orderId\":\"4000061392\",\"shipmentId\":\"SI139193599\",\"stopId\":\"1-70285467558\",\"orderStatus\":\"In-transit\",\"shipmentExecutionStatus\":\"EXECUTION_PENDING\",\"shipmentCapabilityType\":\"CAP_INTMDL STND\",\"lineOfBusiness\":\"IM\",\"stopType\":\"D\",\"locationId\":\"2856142\",\"locationName\":\"AMAZON.COM INC FC LAS7\",\"appointmentActionTraceLog\":\"OrderId:4000061392 OrderStopToken:1-70285467558 StopType:D CapabilityType:CAP_INTMDL STND. Shipment:[SI139193599]EXECUTION_PENDING;LastRailLegShipment:[SI139193598]EXECUTION_PENDING;CrossTownShipment:[SI139193597]EXECUTION_PENDING;OriginDrayShipment:[SI139193595]EXECUTION_DEPARTED LAST STOP;PickUpApptConfirmed:true. Expected ground time less than threshold of -1 hours. CurrentTime=2022-11-04T23:25:57.743-07:00[US/Pacific] Expected GroundTime=2022-10-15T10:00-07:00.Hours \"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true},{\"activityName\":\"RECEIVING FREIGHT\",\"dayOfWeek\":\"SUNDAY\",\"startTime\":\"00:01:00\",\"endTime\":\"23:59:00\",\"openAllDay\":true,\"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true},{\"activityName\":\"LOADING FREIGHT\",\"dayOfWeek\":\"SUNDAY\",\"startTime\":\"00:01:00\",\"endTime\":\"23:59:00\",\"openAllDay\":true,\"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true}]}},\"UIResponse\":{ \"RequestedStartDTTM\":\"2022-10-02\",\" Override24HrsSuggestedDTTM\":\"null\",\"Stop Action\":\"Drop Loaded Trailer\",\"ExceptionRequested\":\"null\"}"
}
```

Here is the response I am getting for my JSON

I want to make `,\"UIResponse\":{ \"RequestedStartDTTM\":\"2022-10-02\",\" Override24HrsSuggestedDTTM\":\"null\",\"Stop Action\":\"Drop Loaded Trailer\",\"ExceptionRequested\":\"null\"}"`

inside the brackets }]}} and make it look like

```
"workItemData": "{\"pendingAppointment\":{\"orderId\":\"4000061392\",\"shipmentId\":\"SI139193599\",\"stopId\":\"1-70285467558\",\"orderStatus\":\"In-transit\",\"shipmentExecutionStatus\":\"EXECUTION_PENDING\",\"shipmentCapabilityType\":\"CAP_INTMDL STND\",\"lineOfBusiness\":\"IM\",\"stopType\":\"D\",\"locationId\":\"2856142\",\"locationName\":\"AMAZON.COM INC FC LAS7\",\"appointmentActionTraceLog\":\"OrderId:4000061392 OrderStopToken:1-70285467558 StopType:D CapabilityType:CAP_INTMDL STND. Shipment:[SI139193599]EXECUTION_PENDING;LastRailLegShipment:[SI139193598]EXECUTION_PENDING;CrossTownShipment:[SI139193597]EXECUTION_PENDING;OriginDrayShipment:[SI139193595]EXECUTION_DEPARTED LAST STOP;PickUpApptConfirmed:true. Expected ground time less than threshold of -1 hours. CurrentTime=2022-11-04T23:25:57.743-07:00[US/Pacific] Expected GroundTime=2022-10-15T10:00-07:00.Hours \"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true},{\"activityName\":\"RECEIVING FREIGHT\",\"dayOfWeek\":\"SUNDAY\",\"startTime\":\"00:01:00\",\"endTime\":\"23:59:00\",\"openAllDay\":true,\"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true},{\"activityName\":\"LOADING FREIGHT\",\"dayOfWeek\":\"SUNDAY\",\"startTime\":\"00:01:00\",\"endTime\":\"23:59:00\",\"openAllDay\":true,\"openAtStartOfDay\":true,\"closeAtEndOfDay\":true,\"isWorkOn\":true,\"UIResponse\":{ \"RequestedStartDTTM\":\"2022-10-02\",\" Override24HrsSuggestedDTTM\":\"null\",\"Stop Action\":\"Drop Loaded Trailer\",\"ExceptionRequested\":\"null\"}}]}}"
}
```

the code I am writing for above is

```
var str=",\""+"UIResponse"+"\"" +":"  +"{ "+"\""+"RequestedStartDTTM"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.overReq + "\","
    +"\""+" Override24HrsSuggestedDTTM"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.oversug + "\","
    +"\""+"Stop Action"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.stopAction1 + "\","
    +"\""+"ExceptionRequested"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.excepReqs + "\"}" ;
    let workData=this.users['workItemData'] + str;
    workData.slice(0,workData.lastIndexOf("}"))+str + "}\"" ;
```

where I am going wrong??

the code I am writing for above is

```
var str=",\""+"UIResponse"+"\"" +":"  +"{ "+"\""+"RequestedStartDTTM"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.overReq + "\","
    +"\""+" Override24HrsSuggestedDTTM"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.oversug + "\","
    +"\""+"Stop Action"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.stopAction1 + "\","
    +"\""+"ExceptionRequested"+"\"" +":\""+this.form41.value.excepReqs + "\"}" ;
    let workData=this.users['workItemData'] + str;
    workData.slice(0,workData.lastIndexOf("}"))+str + "}\"" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand this right... You wanna have a JSON/String object? You can easily convert a JSON to a string and back like:

```
const json = {something: [{price: 10.5}, {price: 15.5}], value: "test"};

const stringJson = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(stringJson);

const backToJson = JSON.parse(stringJson);
console.log(backToJson);
```

So the part you "build" the response can be very easy..

If you wanna combine two JSON objects you can do it like the follow:

```
jsonOne = {test: "Hello", oldProperty: "Hello Old"};
jsonTwo = {test: "Hello 2", newProperty: "Hello New"};
{...jsonOne, ...jsonTwo}
```

The second argument overrides the properties from jsonOne. If a property not exists in jsonOne it will be created. The result of the example will be: `{test: "Hello 2", oldProperty: "Hello old", newProperty: "Hello New"}`

Greetings, Flo